# How to integrate flex swf file in java script?

Tags: javascript

We implemented one concept in Flex and now would like to integrate with JavaScript. Earlier we integrated an Applet code but now, we developed the concept in Flex, however, I am unable to integrate the concept in java script.

Can anyone help me out with the procedure to integrate flex swf file in java script ?

Here is my earlier java script code :

var file=gup('query');
//document.write(file);
var prevFile=gup('prevFileName');
//document.write(prevFile);
document.write("");

document.write("");
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[[]/,"\[").replace(/[]]/,"\]");
  var regexS = "[\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: var file=gup('query');
//document.write(file);
var prevFile=gup('prevFileName');
//document.write(prevFile);
document.write("<table align=\"center\"><tr><td><applet code=\"DELO/MyApplet.class\" archive=\"Visual.jar\" width=1000 height=500>");

document.write("</applet></td></tr></table>");
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear what you're trying to do… But you'd need to use the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class to let JavaScript code call into Flex, and Flex code call into JavaScript. For example, to call a JS function from Flex:

```
var result:* = ExternalInterface.call("myFunction", arg1, arg2)
```

Also, if you're trying to embed the SWF into the HTML page, [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks David, I think I need to refer SWFObject concept.

Comment: Ah, ok — I wasn't entirely sure from your question. If this answers your question, can you hit the checkmark beside it to "accept" the answer?

Comment: Actually, I think SWFObject option is only to play swf video files. I verified the documentation of SWFObject and its purely for video files but am not sure whether it help me to integrate my project.

Comment: It'll work with any `.swf` file (like, for example, the ones generated by Flex Builder). Just follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation